# Chrome keeps logging me out of websites

Tags: chrome-for-android

For the last few months, my Android Pixel 2 XL (running 8, now 9) often shows me the login page on my frequently visited websites. I've managed to reproduce it with these steps:

1. Open Chrome (68.0.3440.85)
2. Visit facebook.com and login
3. Using tab switcher, swipe away (close) Chrome
4. Open Chrome again

Behaviour:
Returns to the facebook page, but asks me to login again

Expected:
A cookie is stored that ensures I'm still logged in

I'm not rooted, have tried rebooting, have ensured I have the latest Chrome version. I haven't tried a factory reset but would like to avoid that if possible. I also have a password manager (Dashlane) that offers to log me in, if that matters.

Comment: From the 3 dots menu> Settings >Site settings>Make sure cookies status is set to *allowed*. Also third party cookies. If already allowed, toggle off and on check if behaviour changes

Comment: Both settings were enabled. I toggled them on and off, but the behaviour persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [confirmed by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200063/chrome-keeps-logging-me-out-of-websites?noredirect=1#comment256277_200063) disabling Chrome app fixed the problem (Settings →apps & notifications → select system apps→Chrome →disable app (to revert to the original version before updates)

I have no idea what caused this problem and only guess is Android Pie + Chrome updates didn't gel